# Solve non square linear system with Math.net

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, math.net

I'm trying to solve a non square linear system with Math.net.
But I get an error *Matrix dimensions must agree: 3x7*.

Here is some example code:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
var mBuilder = Matrix<double>.Build;
var vBuilder = Vector<double>.Build;
var A = mBuilder.DenseOfArray(new double[,]
{
    { 3, 2, 1, 5, -1, 0, 0 },
    { 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, -1, 0 },
    { 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, -1 }
});
var b = vBuilder.DenseOfArray(new double[] { -3, -5, -2 });
Vector<double> x;
x = A.Solve(b);
```

Cleary the system has a solution (e.g. `X = {0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 2}`).
How can I solve such a system with Math.Net?

Comment: Did you try checking if the matrix is actually 3x7 and not 7x3?

Comment: @ZenZac yes `A.Transpose().Solve(b)` gives another error (All vectors must have the same dimensionality)

Comment: Your matrix A seems to be 3x7 and your matrix B seems to be 1x3.  Try transposing B.

Comment: b is a vector. you can't transpose vectors.

Comment: Not the same library, but this should give some more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_vector_transpose.htm

Comment: It seems Math.NET needs the QR decomposition to solve a linear system, but it can't compute the QR decomposition of a matrix if there are more columns than rows. So it's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the Matrix.Solve function with a non-square matrix because there is no  inverse and no unique solutions for a rectangular matrix. Google "inverse of rectangular matrix" for explanations galore. You can use pseudoinverse however, as shown below.

```
        var mBuilder = Matrix<double>.Build;
        var A = mBuilder.DenseOfArray(new double[,]
      {
          { 3, 2, 1, 5, -1, 0, 0 },
          { 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, -1, 0 },
          { 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, -1 }
      });

        Matrix<double> b = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(3, 1);
        b[0, 0] = -3.0;
        b[1, 0] = -5.0;
        b[2, 0] = -2.0;

        var p = A.PseudoInverse();
        var x = p * b;

        // verify
        var o = A * x;
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I had expected the Solve method to find any solution, even if not unique. Using the pseudoinverse is a good idea.